# How can I remove options from Select list without affecting the index?

Tags: javascript

I am writing the following JavaScript which is going to remove some options from a select list:

```
var selectobject = document.getElementById("Approver_90afaad9-2b54-46fb-8ac1-7374e4efa11e_$DropDownChoice");

for (var i = 0; i < selectobject.options.length; i++) {
    var isCM = false;

    for (var ii = 0; ii < assets.length; ii++) {
        if (assets[ii].Title == selectobject.options[i].value) {
            isCM = true;
        }
    }
    if (isCM == false) {
        selectobject.remove(i);
    }
}
```

but the problem I am facing is that is that when I remove an option using `selectobject.remove(i);` then `i` index inside the `selectobject` will be changed so is there a way to preserve the original index after the `selectobject.remove(i);`?? I tried to copy the `selectobject` inside a new `var` but still I faced the same issue...

Thanks

Comment: what about using `splice()`?

Comment: I'm assuming part of the issue is that when the index is changed, items in the select box gets skipped. One way of countering this is to loop in reverse, i.e. `for (var i=selectobject.options.length; i>=0; i--)`. That way, the elements affected by the index change have already been handled.

Comment: @Vilas splice() in my case did not remove the options

Comment: @QuangdaoNguyen so there is not any other way to handle this ??

Comment: @QuangdaoNguyen also in your scenario i need to use "_var i=selectobject.options.length-1_" instead of "_var i=selectobject.options.length_" ?? is this correct ?

Comment: @johnG Oh, yes, you are correct. Apparently I'm too late to edit it...

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround. May be you can use it. Instead of

`selectobject.remove(i);`

You can use :

```
selectobject.style.display = "none";
```

This will even preserve your original index.

Comment: so i will try this approach  just in-case i can not get the remove() working correctly.. as using .remove can be more standard than hiding the options..

Comment: Yes, you are right that using remove() is more standard way :)